# Estadd mean multiple regressions

Tags: stata, mean

I'm building a table with several regressions in it and I'd like to add a *first column* with the means of the independent variables.

I've been using estadd mean but it creates a column after *each* regression, while I would like just one, at the very beginning, after the independent variable's name. Here's the code I've used so far:

```
eststo: xtivreg2 Living_u15 Fst_gender_al ${FB} [pweight=sweight] if tag==1 & v025==2, cluster (sstate senumer) fe ivar(sstate)
 estadd mean

eststo: xtivreg2 Living_hh_u15 Fst_gender_al ${FB} [pweight=sweight] if tag==1 & v025==2, cluster (sstate senumer) fe ivar(sstate)

eststo: xtivreg2 Living_u15 Fst_gender_al ${FB} [pweight=sweight] if tag==1  & Moth_age<35 & v025==2, cluster (sstate senumer) fe ivar(sstate)
eststo: xtivreg2 Living_hh_u15 Fst_gender_al ${FB} [pweight=sweight] if tag==1  & Moth_age<35 & v025==2, cluster (sstate senumer) fe ivar(sstate)

eststo: xtivreg2 Living_u15 Fst_gender_al ${FB} [pweight=sweight] if tag==1 & Moth_age<30 & v025==2, cluster (sstate senumer) fe ivar(sstate)
eststo: xtivreg2 Living_hh_u15 Fst_gender_al ${FB} [pweight=sweight] if tag==1 & Moth_age<30 & v025==2, cluster (sstate senumer) fe ivar(sstate)


esttab using "${ndhs_table}FB_dstat.tex", cell((b mean) se) stat(N r2 F) title(..)  
addnotes(".. ") star(* 0.1 ** 0.05 *** 0.01) append
```

Is there any way I could get around this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use `estpost` with `tabstat` then use the `&` operator inside `cells()` to combine the mean and beta values.

```
sysuse auto, clear
local rhs weight trunk
eststo clear
eststo: estpost tabstat `rhs', stat(mean) col(stat)
eststo: regress price `rhs'
eststo: regress price `rhs', vce(robust)
esttab, cells("mean & b" se)
```

This yields the following.

```
. esttab, cells("mean & b" se) nodepvar

---------------------------------------------------
                      (1)          (2)          (3)
                     est1         est2         est3
                mean/b/se    mean/b/se    mean/b/se
---------------------------------------------------
weight          3019.459      2.266182     2.266182
                              .5110542     .6227162
trunk           13.75676     -60.03885    -60.03885
                              92.85726     88.23694
_cons                         148.5533     148.5533
                              1203.406     947.5387
---------------------------------------------------
N                      74           74           74
---------------------------------------------------
```

Does this help? You may still want to do some tinkering to get the labels and titles just right.